# Generate mathematical functions using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to generate mathematical functions using a for loop (in R) in such a way that I can then recall them by f[3] for i=3, for example.

What I originally tried was:

```
f<-NULL
for (i in 1:100){
    f[i]<-function(x){x*i}
}
```

This doesn't work.  I suspect that this is because the for loop automatically generates a vector, and a function can't fit into a vector.  I also suspect that the fix is fairly simple.  Does anyone know how to generate functions like this?

My real functions are much more complicated, but I wanted to make the question readable.  I will also be repeating this thousands of times, so manually entering in function is not a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.  The first is that you need to use a list rather than a vector.  The second problem is a little more subtle.  If you just do

```
f<-list()
for (i in 1:100){
    f[[i]]<-function(x){x*i}
}
```

This will create a list of functions, but the problem is that the variable `i` will still refer to the global environment.  Since after the loop, the value of `i` is `100` then all of the functions will be the same:

```
> f[[5]](2)
[1] 200
> f[[10]](2)
[1] 200
```

In order to fix this, you can create a new environment to hold the local variables each time through the loop, and assign this environment to the function, as follows:

```
f<-list()
for (i in 1:100){
    e<-new.env()
    e$i<-i
    f[[i]]<-function(x){x*i}
    environment(f[[i]])<-e
}
```

Now each function will look up `i` in its local environment, so it works as expected:

```
> f[[5]](2)
[1] 10
> f[[10]](2)
[1] 20
```

Comment: I need to multiply each f[[i]] by another function h<-function(x){x} and then integrate them from 0 to 1. I've tried many things, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to `force` the evaluation of your index (i) using the...`force` function and you can also replace the `for` loop by `lapply`.

```
size <- 5
f <- function(ind) { force(ind); function(x) x * ind }
fmult <- lapply(seq_len(size), function(i) f(i))
fmult[[3]](4)
## [1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size <- 100L
f<-vector("list", size)
for (i in seq_along(f)){
  f[[i]]<- function(x){x*i}
}
```

You need a list.  Also, note that the `i` in the function is recorded as `i`, not the value of `i`.  If you want the value of `i` that is more complicated, but i'm just answering the question you asked directly.